# Fatal error "could not read Username" when update submodule using git

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've encountered a strange issue, and searched for a long time with no solution.

I have a main project named `lapp-yhkt`(local path: `/g/webstorm/lapp-yhkt`):[image]

and the content of `.gitmodules` :[image]

At this directory, I take the steps from [**Git-Tools-Submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

First init submodule,

```
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'app/base' (https://git.mobcb.com/liteapp/lapp-base.git) registered for path 'app/base'
```

the update it and get fatal error,

```
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'G:/webstorm/lapp-yhkt/app/base'...
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.mobcb.com': Invalid argument
fatal: clone of 'https://git.mobcb.com/liteapp/lapp-base.git' into submodule path 'G:/webstorm/lapp-yhkt/app/base' failed
```

After these, I also tried `git submodule sync` and `git submodule update`:

```
$ git submodule sync
Synchronizing submodule url for 'app/base'


$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'G:/webstorm/lapp-yhkt/app/base'...
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.mobcb.com': Invalid argument
fatal: clone of 'https://git.mobcb.com/liteapp/lapp-base.git' into submodule path 'G:/webstorm/lapp-yhkt/app/base' failed
```

But same error occur to me, it's frustrated. Hope anyone can save me and thanks in advance.

***EDIT:*** I used git in windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution :**

This problem occurrs when one cloned using HTTPS URL and then tried to push the changes using Git Bash on Windows using:

```
git clone https://github.com/{username}/{repo}.git
```

However, when one used SSH URL to clone, this problem doesn't occur:

```
git clone git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git
```

Comment: I've cloned the main project with SSH URL. Maybe I should change the submodule url to SSH URL as well?

Comment: Yes Correct, you may try manually calling `git clone git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git`

Comment: Because it clearly saying `fatal: clone of *** into submodule path *** failed`